# System.OutOfMemoryException due to asp.net worker process

Tags: iis-6

Is it normal if two aspnet_wp.exe process are running in web server? what happened here is that one of the process gradually consuming too much memory. eventually i receive System.OutOfMemoryException when i attempt to acess the web site.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be any number of reasons for your app running out of memory, many of which aren't going to be discovered using task manager, process monitor or performance monitor.

To find out what is truly happening you need to either profile the application using a tool such as [Ants Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) or dig deeper and capture a process dump to analyse in WinDbg + SOS.

Tess Ferrandez has a great series of articles on how to get to the bottom of such problems:

> [If broken, fix it you should - Memory Issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/tags/memory+issues/)

There's also a nice series of tutorials to get you started with ADPlus, WinDBG and SOS:

> [.NET Debugging Demos - Information and setup instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx)
>   [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 3: Memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/15/net-debugging-demos-lab-3-memory.aspx)
>   [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 6: Memory Leak](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/03/17/net-debugging-demos-lab-6-memory-leak.aspx)
>   [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 7: Memory Leak](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/03/25/net-debugging-demos-lab-7-memory-leak.aspx)