# w3wp.exe RAM usage problem

Tags: iis-7

We have publishing .Net based web site that is running IIS 7.0 on the Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.Otherwise,I have SQL Server on a different server.
Both IBM x3650 server has 32 Gb RAM.Sometimes, the w3wp.exe service using 20 Gb of the memory on the IIS.What should I do?

Thanks,

Comment: is the amount of memory increasing in time? What you could do is to monitor the amount of ram usage and then try to find the relations between the increase in ram usage and the jobs? events? that are executed at that specific time to pinpoint the memory leaks.

Comment: ub1k- As you said yes,increasing.

Comment: Whilst the question is about an out of memory exception, the same principles apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305172/system-outofmemoryexception-due-to-asp-net-worker-process/6307393#6307393

Answer (score 2):

Any chance you're using URLRewritingNet to rewrite your URLs?
I experienced a serious performance issue with it on Windows Server 2008 R2 using IIS7 that caused the w3wpe.exe to max out, even when there was a single user!  The fix was to scrap that library and use IIS7 Rewrite rules instead.

The issue is very nicely documented here: http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/urlrewritingnet-performance-issues

Best of luck,
David

Comment: Hi,  thank you very much for that link.  I am not using URL Rewriting and now probably never will :)

Answer (score 0):

Well then again. It's a hard problem finding memory leaks. first do some logging presumably on every request you get -> and log the amount of memory that is being used. Then find all your jobs -> and possible parts of code that may generate leaks (as long as their not executed during every request) and also log their beginning and end.

When you do that you can afterwards check your logs and search for parts in which the memory usage significantly increases, then possibly you can pinpoint what part of your code is generating leaks.

The other thing is you can search for "memory leaks WHAT YOU USE" where WHAT YOU USE is some mechanisms that you're using whatever they might be.

On the other hand there are number of things that you should do to avoid memory leaks, first of them that comes to my mind is exploring the `using()` statement.

Oh. Don't think you'll find the problem in the next 20mins. It will rather take days (when trying to debug it with logging)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I think I need to be clearer in my question. I do not think I am having a memory leak. The memory goes up to 140,000k on loading the image and then resides back down again to 130,000k. I was just curious to know whether by getting more RAM whether it has an affect on w3wp memory cache.  I am assuming that this process goes up when loading and goes down when garbage collection kicks in? I am only guess as I am learning IIS administration as I type :)